# codeigniter - pass data to view

Tags: php, codeigniter, argument-passing

Ok I have a simple question I am using codeigniter frame work to create a simple blog. When I set up just a controller and a view I can print my database information (blog roll) to my view just fine. When I use the model controller view method i fail.

Here is what I would like to implement in to a method controller view setup.

my original view that works:

```
<?php
//is there an array from your search form?
if($_GET){

$books = $this->db->get('blog');//query the blog table in the database
if($books->num_rows() < 1)//are there clients to show?
{
    echo 'There are no blog post'; //error message if no post
}

else
{
    foreach(result() as $row)//loop through the blog
    {
        echo $row->title."<br>";//display each titles info
    }
}
}
?>
```

This is what i have set for my New **model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Blog_Model extends CI_Model {

function get($args = null)
{
    $query = $this->db->get('blog');
    return $query->result();
    foreach(result() as $row)//loop through the books

}

function insert($data)
{

    $this->db->insert('blog', $data);
}

function update($data,$id)
{
    $this->db->where("id",$id);

    $this->db->update('blog', $data);
}
 function delete($id)
{
    $this->db->where("id",$id);


    $this->db->delete('blog');
}
}
```

this is my new **controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Blog extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('blog_model', 'blog');
    $data['blogs'] = $this->blog->get();
    $this->load->view('blog',$data);

}


}
```

I am not sure what to do for my new view? I just want to echo the blog roll to the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you´re doing a foreach in the model after the return function.

So what you return is just this:

`$query->result()`

You may should do the foreach in the view, this would be better placed as a model just should just return and not process information. Best place would be in this case the controller or may view - depending on how strict you are.

I did not work with CodeIgniter for a while so may try this:
**Controller**:

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('blog_model', 'blog');
        $data['blogs'] = $this->blog_model->get()->result();
        $this->load->view('blog',$data);

    }


}
```

The **View**

```
Here goes some text...
<?php
    foreach($blogs as $post)
    {
       echo $post['someData'];
       echo $post['someData2'];
    }
?>
After all this code...
```

May you want to lookup [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) (CodeIgniter Doc).

Hope this helps. Try to

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
$data['blogs'] = $this->blog_model->get();
```

Even though you load the model in order to call its function you must pass its name.

**Model:**

Must always have `result()` or `row()` when query are applied.

Hope this helps in your endeavors